# Copyrights for answers

Tags: discussion, rules

So, I'm writing some code as an application project to a high school, because, who needs videos or Powerpoints when you can design a website as your submission. Anyways, I've been getting debugging help on Stack Overflow, and parts of my code are taken from answers. I've reorganized some of them just to fit into my coding style, just changing up spacing and locations of minor pieces of code, as well as changing variable names, as I like to make up fake names when posting code on SO. My question is, since this is technically an academic work, do I need to credit the people who helped me, and if so, how? Would I add comments to parts of my code, put it in the description of the code that I will sumbit as a separate word document, or something else. I feel like this might be a quite silly question, but I don't wan  to get in any trouble.

Comment: "Copyright" and "credit" are two separate concerns. Even if the copyright license doesn't require it, for any academic work or other work that is presumed to be original, you need to credit your sources.

Comment: Alright, worded it wrong. I'm looking to see if there's a correct/preferable way to credit my sources, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like something that would be decided by your school/teacher. Most will have a "code of academic conduct" or something along those lines to define acceptable collaboration levels.

As far as we are concerned, [we published attribution guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) for republishing content from Stack Overflow. What you're doing isn't republishing per se, but giving credit where it's due is always a good move.

Comment: I don't know about the school's code of conduct, I'll look into it, but about the attribution guidelines, it seems to be the case that I need to hyperlink to each question relating to code used for the creation of my site. Am I reading it correctly?

Comment: @BillBllson Question or answer, whichever makes the most sense.

Comment: @BillBllson also note that there is difference between "copy content" vs. "apply idea" (distinction covered in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/re-using-ideas-or-small-pieces-of-code-from-stackoverflow-com/). General thanks is still nice (and may even be required based on your school rules) but you don't need to mark every null check with "check for null is courtesy of John Sounders taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)"